# What is the orthogonal of an intersection?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

**Background**

I have been introduced to the notion of orthogonal complement of a subset of a (pre)hilbert space. Given $X$ a (pre)hilbert space and $A\subseteq X$, one defines $A^\perp:=\{x\in X:x\perp A\}$. I have then been encouraged to try finding out what happens if, given $A,B\subseteq X$, I try finding $(A\cup B)^\perp$ or $(A\cap B)^\perp$. I think I have managed the former, with it being $A^\perp\cap B^\perp$. Indeed, if $x\perp A\cup B$, then $x\perp A, x\perp B$, thus $x\in A^\perp\cap B^\perp$. Conversely, if $x\in A^\perp\cap B^\perp$, then $x\perp A,x\perp B$, so for all $z\in A\cup B$, since $z\in A\vee z\in B$, we have $x\perp z$, giving $x\perp A\cup B$.

My intuition led me to thinking that, since $A^\perp\cup B^\perp$ does not fill the whole of $(A\cap B)^\perp$, I might have $(A\cap B)^\perp=A^\perp+B^\perp$, where if $P,Q\leq X$ are subspaces, then $P+Q:=\mathrm{span}(P\cup Q)=$ $=\{p+q:p\in P,q\in Q\}$. I have managed to prove one inclusion. If $x\in A^\perp+B^\perp$, then $x=a+b$ where $a\perp A,b\perp B$. Then: $\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$
$$\ang{x,z}=\ang{a,z}+\ang{b,z}=0,$$
for all $z\in A\cap B$. Thus, $A^\perp+B^\perp\subseteq(A\cap B)^\perp$. Trouble is, I cannot seem to manage the other inclusion.

**Question**

- Is it true that $(A\cap B)^\perp=A^\perp+B^\perp$? Does this require the space to be a Hilbert space or is it valid for prehilbert spaces too?
- How do I prove it?
- Can you give me a counterexample if it's not true? And in that case, is there a way to express $(A\cap B)^\perp$ in terms of $A^\perp,B^\perp$? If so, how do I prove it holds?

**Update:**
Since I haven't received an answer in $31+31+28-9=62+19=83$ days, I tried thinking up one for myself, then got stuck again. Here is what I tried. We want to prove $(A\cap B)^\perp\subseteq A^\perp+B^\perp$. We just need to prove $(A^\perp+B^\perp)^C\subseteq[(A\cap B)^\perp]^C$, i.e. $x\not\in A^\perp+B^\perp\implies x\not\in(A\cap B)^\perp$. So let $x\not\in A^\perp+B^\perp$. This means we can write it as $p+t$, where $p$ is its projection on the subspace $A^\perp+B^\perp$ and can therefore be written as $p=a+b$ with $a\perp A,b\perp B$, and $t=x-p=x-a-b$. So:
$$x=a+b+t,$$
with $a\perp A,b\perp B,t\not\in(A^\perp+B^\perp)$. Obviously, if $t\perp A$ or $t\perp B$, then we put it together with $a$ or $b$ respectively, ending up with $x\in A^\perp+B^\perp$, which is not the case. So we have $t\not\in(A^\perp\cup B^\perp)$, meaning there exist $a_t\in A,b_t\in B:a_t\not\perp t,b_t\not\perp t$. Of course, they are all nonzero, for $t\neq0$ otherwise $x\in A^\perp+B^\perp$, and the non-perpendicularity of $a_t,b_t$ with $t$ gives that they are nonzero otherwise they would be orthogonal to any vector, $t$ included. We can see that:
$$\langle x,z\rangle=\langle a,z\rangle+\langle b,z\rangle+\langle t,z\rangle\underset{\substack{|\\z\in(A\cap B)^\perp}}{=}\langle t,z\rangle.$$
We need to show there exists $z\in(A\cap B)^\perp$ such that that is nonzero. That is where I got stuck again. First of all, if any of $a_t,b_t$ lie in the intersection, we are done. Suppose neither lies there. I then tried considering their projections $a',b'$ onto the intersection. How do I prove any of those are not orthogonal to $t$?

**Update 2:**
Let us consider $t$. We know that $t=x-p$ with $p$ being the projection of $x$ onto the sum of the orthogonal. But then we know $t$ is orthogonal to that sum, so it is orthogonal to both orthogonals, so it is in both the biorthogonals, $t\in(A^\perp)^\perp\cap(B^\perp)^\perp$. But we know that $(A^\perp)^\perp=\overline{\operatorname{lin}A}$, at least in hilbert spaces, so $t\in\overline{\operatorname{lin}A}\cap\overline{\operatorname{lin}B}$. What is the intersection of the closures of the linear spans in relation with the intersection? Is it contained in the closure of the linear span of the intersection? I guess it is only the opposite. Also because I got an answer as I wrote this in the answer box :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question
>
> 1. Is it true that $(A\cap B)^\perp=A^\perp+B^\perp$?
> 2. Does this require the space to be a Hilbert space or is it valid for  prehilbert spaces too?
> 3. How do I prove it? Can you give me a  counterexample if it's not true? And in that case, is there a way to express $(A∩B)^\perp$ in
>    terms of $ A^\perp$, $B^\perp$? If so, how do I prove it holds?

1. No.
2. It's true on **Hilbert space** if $A$ and $B$ are closed spaces

($(A^\perp)^\perp$ can be different from $\overline A$ on prehilbert space ([ex.](https://math-os.com/orthogonal-sev/)))

3. Consider $E=\mathcal{C}(\left[-1,1\right],\mathbb{R})$, with inner product :

   $$\forall\left(f,g\right)\in E^{2},\thinspace\left(f\mid g\right)=\int_{-1}^{1}f\left(t\right)g\left(t\right)\thinspace dt$$
   and

   $$D=\left\{f\in E;\,\forall t\in\left[0,1\right],\thinspace f\left(t\right)=0\right\}$$
   et

   $$G=\left\{f\in E;\,\forall t\in\left[-1,0\right],\thinspace f\left(t\right)=0\right\}$$

One can prove  [in french...](https://math-os.com/orthogonal-sev/) that $D^\perp=G$ and $G^\perp=D$.

On one hand $(D\cap G)^\perp=\{0_E\}^\perp=E$

And on the other  $D^\perp+G^\perp=G+D\neq E$

since $\forall f\in G+D$, $f(0)=0$.

This is also a counterexample for $(D^\perp)^\perp=D$ but $D\oplus D^\perp\neq E$.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that $(A\cap B)^\perp$ is the closure of $A^\perp+B^\perp$ when $A$ and $B$ are closed subspaces.  Because [there are closed subspaces whose sums are not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/135471/), the result you tried to prove does not hold in general.  (The link speaks of "direct" sums, which means the subspaces also have zero intersection.)

**From comments**

If $A,B$ are two closed subspaces, we know that $A^{\perp\perp}=A,B^{\perp\perp}=B$. Let us now consider $(A^{\perp}+B^\perp)^\perp$. If $a\in(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp$, then $a\perp A^\perp,a\perp B^\perp$. Thus $a\in A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}=A\cap B$. If, instead, $a\in A\cap B$, then $a\in A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}$. Hence, $a\perp A^\perp,a\perp B^\perp$. Therefore, if $x\in A^\perp+B^\perp$, since $x=a'+b$ with $a'\perp A,b\perp B$, we have $\langle a,x\rangle=\langle a,a'\rangle+\langle a,b\rangle$, which is a sum of two zeros since $a\perp A^\perp\ni a'$ and $a\perp B^\perp\ni b$. Thus, $a\perp A^\perp+B^\perp$. So we have proved that:
$$(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp=A\cap B.$$
Take the orhogonal of both sides, and $(A\cap B)^\perp=(A^\perp+B^\perp)^{\perp\perp}$. The biorthogonal of something is the closure of its linear span. The linear span of $A^\perp+B^\perp$, since it is a linear subspace, is $A^\perp+B^\perp$ itself. Thus, we have that, if $A,B$ are closed subspaces:
$$(A\cap B)^\perp=\overline{A^\perp+B^\perp}.$$

If, however, $A,B$ are not closed subspaces, we have $A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}\supseteq A\cap B$, so $(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp\supseteq A\cap B$ (since $(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp=A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}$ still holds), and taking the orthogonal gives:
$$\overline{A^\perp+B^\perp}\subseteq(A\cap B)^\perp.$$
There is not much more to say about this. In general, there won't be an easy expression of the orthogonal of an intersection in terms of the single orthogonals.

**Final addendum**

If $A,B$ are dense linear subspaces, then $A^{\perp\perp}=B^{\perp\perp}=X$, so $A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}=X\cap X=X$, and $(A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp})^\perp=X^\perp=\{0\}$. Thus, $A^\perp+B^\perp=\{0\}$, which could be inferred from $A^\perp=B^\perp=\{0\}$. If furthermore $A\cap B=\{0\}$, then $(A\cap B)^\perp=\{0\}^\perp=X$. So:
$$(A\cap B)^\perp=X\supsetneq\{0\}=\overline{A^\perp+B^\perp}.$$
Just for an extreme example.

Comment: OK, I admit I should have thought about the closure. But how do I prove that? PS the second update is just to save, and to show others, what I tried after the first update. And how I failed again :).

Comment: @MickG: If you know that $K^{\perp\perp}$ is the closure of $K$ when $K$ is a linear subspace of Hilbert space, here's a proof that uses that fact: If $A$ and $B$ are closed subspaces, then $(A^\perp + B^\perp)^\perp = A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}=A\cap B$, hence the closure of $A^\perp+B^\perp$ is $(A^\perp + B^\perp)^{\perp\perp}=(A\cap B)^\perp$.  (In any case, it might be easier to prove now that you have the correct statement.)

Comment: OK, I want to show $(A^\perp+B^\perp)^\perp=A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}$. If $x\perp(A^\perp+B^\perp)$, then $x\perp A^\perp,x\perp B^\perp$, so $x\in A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}$. If $x\in A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp}$, then for $z\in A^\perp+B^\perp$, since $z=a+b$ with $a\perp A,b\perp B$, we have $\langle x,z\rangle=\langle x,a\rangle+\langle x,b\rangle=0+0=0$, so $x\perp A^\perp+B^\perp$. And that was easy. But what if $A,B$ are just convex sets and not closed subspaces? That equality still holds, but the second step doesn't. The second step will have $\cap$closed spans.

Comment: I will therefore get $\overline{A^\perp+B^\perp}=(\overline{ \operatorname{lin}A}\cap\overline{\operatorname{lin}B})^\perp$. This certainly contains $(A\cap B)^\perp$, but is not the same as it. So it seems the result only works for closed subspaces. Right?

Comment: And would you please add these comments to your answer?

Comment: @MickG, I don't plan to.  I've now made my answer community wiki, and you are welcome to add to it.  I agree that it could fail if $A$ and $B$ are not closed subspaces, which seemed to be a tacit assumption in your problem.  If they are not closed, $(A\cap B)^\perp$ can be much larger than $(A^{\perp\perp}\cap B^{\perp\perp})^\perp$, e.g. by taking dense linear subspaces with trivial intersection.