# Linear Algebra - How does this Dimension Counting Argument Work?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading a book on PDE in which the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) and the Rayleigh quotient are mentioned. In the 'compact operators' section in the given link, it seems to me that the proof employs the following proposition.

**Proposition** Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with a countable , linearly independent subset $B=\{u_i:i=1,2,\dots\}$. Let $k$ be any positive integer.

If $B$ is in fact a basis for $H$, it is true that

**(a)** Let $S_k$ be any $k$-dimensional subspace of $H$ and let $S'=\overline{span\{u_i:i\geq k\}}$. Then $S'\cap S_k\neq \{0\}$.

**(b)** Let $V_{k-1}$ be any $k-1$-dimensional subspace of $H$ and let $V'=span\{u_i:1\leq i\leq k\}$. Then $V'\cap {V_{k-1}}^{\perp}\neq \{0\}$.

I know that this probably is very trivial but I just cannot see why they hold since I haven't touched linear algebra for a long time. If $H$ is finite-dimensional, say $\dim(H)=n$, then the proposition is clearly true because we know that
$$\dim(S'\cap S_k)=\dim(S')+\dim(S_k)-\dim(S'+S_k)\geq (n-k+1)+k-n=1>0$$
$$\dim(V'\cap {V_{k-1}}^{\perp})\geq k+[n-(k-1)]-n=1>0$$

But how do we perform dimension counting arguments when $H$ is infinite-dimensional? Thank you.

Comment: Oh... wait... I think I may have missed the phrase "If $B$ is in fact a basis for $H$..." so I think I have to retract all of my previous comments.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry. I edited my question after your comment was made. You are correct in that the proposition is false without the additional assumption.

Comment: I tried to prove (a) and (b) by contradiction, but the only formulas that I know are https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077537/what-is-the-orthogonal-of-an-intersection. For instance, if $S'\cap S_k=\{0\}$, then ${S'}^{\perp}+{S_k}^{\perp}={\{0\}}^{\perp}=H$. I'm not sure what the last identity leads to.