# Closed plus finite dimensional in a TVS

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $E$ is a topological vector space (TVS), $F_1$ a closed subspace of $E$, and $F_2$ a finite dimensional subspace of $E$, such that $F_1 \cap F_2=\{0\}$, is $F_1+F_2$ necessarily closed? If yes, are the projection from $F_1+F_2$ onto $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively, continuous?

Answer (score 3):

Yes If we suppose that $E$ is a normed space , the sum of a closed subspace $Y$ and a finite dimensional space $F$ is closed, in fact :
suppose that a sequence $(y_n+f_n) \subset Y+F$ converge vers $x\in X$, Let $P$ the (continuous Why? ) projection from $Y+F$ to $F$, the sequence $(y_n+f_n)$ is bounded (because it converge to $x$ so it exist a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that converge to $f\in F$ (because F is finite dimensional vector space so every bounded closed set is compact) and so $y_{n_k}$ converge to $y\in Y$ as difference of two convergent sequences, and so $x=y+f\in Y+F$

To complete the proof we need to proof that the  projection from $Y+F$ to $F$ is continuous, so for that we put 
$$
\delta=\min\{d(f,Y) : \|f\|=1 \}
$$
$\delta>0$ because the set $S_F=\{ f\in F ; \|f\|=1\}$ is compact, and the function $d(.,Y)$ is a continuous function so it exist $f'\in S_F$ such that $\delta=d(f',Y)$, then if $\delta=0$ this implies that $f'\in Y\cap F=\{0\}$ but $\|f'\|=1\neq 0$, absurde.

so 
$$
\|y+f\|\geq \delta\|f\|
$$
so the projection from $Y+F$ to $F$ is of norme $\leq \delta^{-1}$

and the projection from $Y+F$ to $Y$ is of norme $\leq 1+\delta^{-1}$

Comment: The sum of two closed subspaces is not necessarily closed. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space Clealrly that one of the subspaces is finite dimensional must be important.

Comment: yeah that true I will correct the proof

Comment: The proof assumes continuity of the projection. As far as I remember, however the subtlty of closed subspaces is equivalent to  the spaces being closed. That might be the flaw in the proof.

Comment: no I proof the continuity of projection on the second part, for this I need the normed structure. @Freeze_S

Comment: I think you have to explain better why $\delta>0$, that's the crux of the entire argument. If $\delta=0$, the argument fails.

Comment: @Markus I think it's clear now :)

Comment: @Hamza Yes, and compactness of the unit ball is why it works when one space is finite dimensional. That inf can be zero when both spaces are infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

**Whenever N,F are subspaces of a TVS, N closed and F finite-dimensional, N+F is closed.**
This is Theorem 1.42 (p. 30) in Rudin: Functional Analysis, 2nd edition, 1991.
https://archive.org/details/RudinW.FunctionalAnalysis2e1991

But even if the TVS is Hilbert, F being closed is not enough (By Exercise 1.20, p. 40), it must be finite-dimensional.

Theorem 5.16b (p. 126):
**If N and F are closed subspaces of an F-space N+F, and $N\cap F=\{0\}$, then the projection $P:A+B\to A$ with null space $B$ is continuous.**

So to your first question the answer is "yes", to the second "yes if N+F is an F-space" but not in general, by Exercise 5.9.

Exercise 5.9 (p. 145): Here $N,F$ are closed subspaces over $L^2(0,1)$, $N\cap F=\{0\}$ but yet $P$ is not continuous.

Note: it is not enough that N,F are closed subspaces of the F-space $L^2$; the space $N+F$ should be complete (F-space).

Def. 1.8e: *F-space* = TVS whose topology is induced by a complete invariant metric (equivalently, TVS having a complete N1 topology, by Theorem 1.24)

BTW, only in Theorem 1.42 finite-dimensionality is assumed, not in the others. 
In Rudin, TVSs are Hausdorff.