# Finite sum of convex closed sets.

Tags: normed-spaces

In a normed space, is the finite sum of closed convex subsets which containing zero closed convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about sum ($A+B = \{a+b \; : a \in A, b \in B\}$) and not union.

No, in infinite dimensions the sum of two closed convex subsets need not be closed.  For example, in a Banach space the sum of two closed subspaces need not be closed. See e.g. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space/135547#135547) for a counterexample in a Hilbert space.

EDIT: This is also true for $\mathbb R^2$.  Consider $A = \{(x,y): y \ge e^x-1 \}$ and $B$ the nonnegative $x$ axis $\{(x,0): x \ge 0\}$.
For any $y > -1$, $(0,y) \in A + B$ because we can write it as $(-x, y) + (x,y)$ for some $x > 0$ such that $e^{-x} < 1 + y$, but $(0,-1) \notin A + B$.