# Is it true that: $V$ is isomorphic to $U$ and $W$ $\Longrightarrow$ $V$ isomorphic to $U + W$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $V$,$U$ and $W$ be closed and infinite dimensional subspaces of $\ell^2$ such that $V$ is isomorphic to $U$ and $W$

My question: Is $V$ isomorphic to $U + W$

Thanks.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$V$ is isomorphic to $U$ and $W$" ? Does it mean "$V$ is isomorphic to $U$ and $V$ is isomorphic to $W$"?

Comment: @GEdgar yes it is

Comment: By isomorphic you mean isometrically isomorphic, right?

Comment: @mechanodroid yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as stated is no.

Let $V = \overline{\operatorname{span} \{e_{2n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}$ and $U = \overline{\operatorname{span} \left\{e_{2n} + \frac{e_{2n+1}}{n+1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}$.

Then $U, V$ are infinite-dimensional closed subspaces of $\ell^2$ and $V \cong V$, $V \cong U$. The latter are isometrically isomorphic via $$e_{2n} \mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac1{(n+1)^2}}} \left(e_{2n} + \frac{e_{2n+1}}{n+1}\right)$$

However, it is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786792/144766) that $V + U$ is not closed so it is not complete. But $V$ is complete so $V$ and $V + U$ cannot be isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

No in general, as sum of two closed subspace is not necessarily closed. See:  [The direct sum of two closed subspace is closed? (Hilbert space)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space/135547#135547)

However, if $W + U$ happens to be closed, then both $V$ and $W + U$ will be isomorphic to $\ell^2$ itself, as infinite dimensional subspace of separable Hilbert space is also a separable Hilbert space. Hence, $V \cong \ell^2 \cong W + U$.

Comment: now I edited that the spaces are infinite dimensional.

Comment: In fact every Hilbert space with countable Schauder Basis (or eqv. separable) is isomorphic to $\ell^2$. This is true for closed $\infty$-dimensional subspace of $\ell^2$. So the answer must be yes now.

Comment: thanks @Nik Pronko for your answer P.S. if you put your comment in an answer i can sign it as answered

Comment: No it still can be wrong as sum of two closed subspaces is not necessarily closed. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space/135547#135547

Comment: you are right but if the sum is closed my question is true?

Comment: Yes, then all subspaces just isomorphic to $\ell^2$.

Comment: thanks for your kindness